# PHP | a prepare/execute didn't work

Tags: php, select, while-loop

I have a problem with a part of my code. I added some examples in the database

```
<?php
 require_once 'db.php';
 $res = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM bien");
 $res2 = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM bien_option WHERE id_bien=:id");
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<h2>Mes Biens:</h2>
<?php

while($mesBiens = $res->fetch()){
    echo '<h3>Nom : '.$mesBiens['nom'].'</h3>';
    echo 'Type : '.$mesBiens['type'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Prix : '.$mesBiens['prix'].'€<br/>';
    echo 'Surface : '.$mesBiens['surface'].'m²<br/>';
    while($mesOptions = $res2->fetch()){
        $res = $bdd->execute(array(':id'=>$mesBiens['id']));
        echo $mesOptions['nom'];
    }
}



?>
```

`echo mesOptions['nom']` didn't show anything and I received no error message.

Comment: when i added it before the while i get this :

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp64\www\ex1\index.php on line 18                     
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in C:\wamp64\www\ex1\index.php on line 18

Comment: "I added some examples in the bdd" — I don't see anything related to BDD in the question.

Comment: sorry "bdd" is the french word for "db" database ^^'

Comment: Ah, it (and the tag you used) means [Behavior Driven Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bdd)

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute your statement.

This queries from the database directly:

```
$res = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM bien");
```

This prepares the statement on the server. Think about it as telling the database you are going to send a lot of these queries in the next time. The database does "compile" this statement so it's efficient:

```
$statment = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM bien_option WHERE id_bien=:id");
```

Now you have to bind a value (the :id) and [execute it](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

At this point the database executed the SQL using your parameter and prepared a result for you, which you need to call now:

```
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Or, if you prefer to have it in a loop:

```
while($mesBiens = $statement->fetch()) { ... }
```

Please note, preparing statements make a lot of sense if you repeat the query often.

Answer (score 0):

So i just edited some things and it's work :)

```
while($mesBiens = $res->fetch()){
    echo '<h3>Nom : '.$mesBiens['nom'].'</h3>';
    echo 'Type : '.$mesBiens['type'].'<br/>';
    echo 'Prix : '.$mesBiens['prix'].'€<br/>';
    echo 'Surface : '.$mesBiens['surface'].'m²<br/>';
    $options = $res2->execute(array(':id'=>$mesBiens['id'])); 

    while($mesOptions = $res2->fetch()) { 
        echo 'Option: '.$mesOptions['nom'].'<br/>'; 
    }
}
```